# Iterate files in a directory - emitting commands with arguments containing %

Tags: windows, scripting, imagemagick, command-line-interface

This CLI-Command on windows-7 with installed ImageMagick tool does it's job for a single file

```
$convert O35C3737.jpg -gravity Center -crop 20%x+0+0  cropped20_O35C3737.jpg
```

Now I try to do the same for all files in a folder containing a BAT-file with this:

```
for %%i in (*.jpg) do convert %%i -gravity Center -crop 20%x+0+0  cc20_%%i
```

Obviously this fails, because the argument 20%x+0+0 of the convert command to be emitted is misinterpreted by the CLI batch-processor and 'eaten away'.

Instead of the desired converted files, I get a batch of error messages by convert command, that does not receive correctly it's expected arguments:

```
$for %i in (*.jpg) do convert %i -gravity Center -crop 20i

    $convert O35C3737.jpg -gravity Center -crop 20i
    convert: invalid argument for option '-crop': 20i @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1225.
```

How can I get through that?

Comment: I am not a Windows user, but in Bat files of ImageMagick commands, I believe you need to double your % in your crop command. Also depending upon output format, you should add +repage after the crop. Another approach to process all files in a folder is to use the ImageMagick mogrify command. In ImageMagick 7, convert is replaced by magick and mogrify becomes magick mogrify.

Comment: Thanks, doubling to %% vor the Imagemagic part, too - this does the trick